# Automated Web Testing Coding Practices?

Tags: automated-tests

I am trying to develop automated tests to perform regression testing on a website. Are there any code conventions I should pass on the developers in order to make my tests more maintainable?

One of the things I have come up with is using static identifiers for html elements. Currently elements are being identified by dynamic id which make my tests virtually unmaintainable.

Comment: What kind of development are they doing? Asp.Net, Ruby, HTML5, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static IDs are pretty much a must. If possible, ask your developers to give you the same UI string resources they are using. Then use those strings, that way your tests won't brake when "Login" is changed to "Log in".

Sometimes designers ask for specially styled drop down list or other form elements. Then developers go and implement those in weird ways. For example using input field with hidden select element, which is shown only when input gets onClick event. Testing those can be a nightmare and those bring up lots of quality issues. Try to avoid those.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the need of fixed element IDs, there shouldn't be anything else required. Tests should not influence the way pages are written.